# Should I replace the whole thing? PVC under sink

Tags: plumbing, pvc

looking to replace my p trap system under the kitchen sink. It’s old . The actual pipe that suppose to curve up to the sink drain is rotted under so I need to unscrew the nut and replace it .

I prefer to replace the whole thing with PVC . How would I go about doing that? What would you do?

[image: P trap system under the sink]

Comment: Sure, plastic should be cheaper than metal. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-can-i-replace-this-corroded-metal-p-trap-with-a-new-pvc-trap

Comment: And would last longer, too, **if you do not use NaOH-based drtain cleaners**, which can get hot enough to melt plastics.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trap arm is soldered to the house drain pipe in the wall.
I suspect the in-wall pipe is copper DWV, as I see no threaded joint that is the usual point of attachment for "PVC" under-sink tubular drain systems. The easiest thing would be to use a rubber coupler sized to fit 1 1/2 tubular drain, between the solder joint sleeve and the new trap arm. (PVC in quotes above because actual PVC tubular drain parts are largely a thing of the past, which is sad because they were vastly superior to the mostly polypropylene stuff universally used nowadays).

Comment: In my area of the US, ( south east) , PVC drain parts are easily purchased.

Comment: The only PVC drain trap parts around me (Midwest US) are for glued assembly only. The screw together ones (very highly recommended for simplicity of installation _and_ future maintenance) are all polypropylene.

Comment: *Shielded* rubber coupler, right?